# How to display calculated model property validation message in view?

Tags: validation, model-view-controller

I want to display the validation error message for a calculated model property called `AtLeastOneSelected` in the view but it will not display. I have the following in my model:

```
[RegularExpression("true", ErrorMessage = "you must select at least one")]
public bool AtLeastOneSelected { get { return PropertyOne != false ||
PropertyTwo != false || PropertyThree != false || PropertyFour != false }

public bool PropertyOne { get; set; }
public bool PropertyTwo { get; set; }
public bool PropertyThree { get; set; }
public bool PropertyFour { get; set; }
```

But the validation message for `AtLeastOneSelected` does not get displayed in the view if I use the following, even though the modelstate is not valid until one of the properties has been selected:

```
 @Html.ValidationMessage("AtLeastOneSelected")
```

I'm aware I could make a custom validation attribute to validate the above, but I think there would be the same problem because I want to display the validation message in one place based on whether at least one of the other properties = true and not have one error message for each property that must be true.

How can I display the error message for the `AtLeastOneSelected` property in the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out AtLeastOneSelected property was having a string added as a prefix to it which meant it did not match the validation summary message in the view when the model is returned with an error in the modelstate.